# Decorating an interface with a decorator using structuremap 3 in an modular application

Tags: c#, module, decorator, ioc-container, structuremap

I'm using `Structuremap 3` and have 3 modules in my `WinForm` project(each module is a class library project):

Core Module contains:

```
  public class ICommandHandler<T>
  {
  }
```

**[Updated]**

```
  public abstract class UnitOfWorkCommitCommandHandlerDecorator<TUnitOfWork, TCommand> :   ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
  {
  }
```

---

Module1 contains:

```
  public interface IModule1UOW: IUnitOfWork
  {
  }

  public class Module1UOW:IModule1UOW
  {
  }

  public class Module1UOWDecorator<TCommand> :UnitOfWorkCommitCommandHandlerDecorator<IModule1UOW,TCommand>
  {
      public Module1UOWDecorator(ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated, IModule1UOW uow)
      {
        ...
      }
  } 

  public Command1
  {
  }
```

---

Module2 contains:

```
  public interface IModule2UOW: IUnitOfWork
  {
  }

  public class Module2UOW:IModule2UOW
  {
  }

  public class Module2UOWDecorator<TCommand> :UnitOfWorkCommitCommandHandlerDecorator<IModule2UOW,TCommand>
      public Module2UOWDecorator(ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated, IModule2UOW uow)
      {
        ...
      }
  } 

  public Command2
  {
  }
```

and defined following classes to configure each module registrations:

```
public class Module1Config
{
    public static void Config()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(s =>
            {
                s.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(Command1));
                s.WithDefaultConventions();
                x.For(typeof(IModule1UOW))
                    .Use(typeof(Module1UOW))
                    .SetLifecycleTo((Lifecycles.Singleton));
                x.For(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
                    .DecorateAllWith(typeof(Module1UOWDecorator<>));
            });
        });
    }
}
public class Module2Config
{
    public static void Config()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(s =>
            {
                s.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(Command2));
                s.WithDefaultConventions();
                x.For(typeof(IModule2UOW))
                    .Use(typeof(Module2UOW))
                    .SetLifecycleTo((Lifecycles.Singleton));
                x.For(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
                    .DecorateAllWith(typeof(Module2UOWDecorator<>));
            });
        });
    }
}
```

At start point of my application(I'm using WinForms so at program.cs) I call `Module1Confog.Config()` and then `Module2Config.Config()`.

When I get an `ICommandHandler<Command2>` instance from `ObjectFactory` I expected an `ICommandHandler<Command2>` object that decorated with `Module2UOWDecorator` but I get an `ICommandHandler<Command2>` object that decorated with `Module2UOWDecorator` and again decorated with `Module1UOWDecorator`.

In the other word I expect :

> `Module2UOWDecorator[ICommandHandler<Command2>]`

but I get

> `Module1UOWDecorator[Module2UOWDecorator[ICommandHandler<Command2>]]`

Does anyone know, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *container* will process the configurations defined within the various modules and will merge them all into a single working configuration. The *container* will not treat the different modules as separate configurations.

But you can still do what you want as the `DecorateAllWith` method has an optional `filter` parameter for deciding what will, and will not, be decorated.

Based on the example above you could try something like this:

```
x.For(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
    .DecorateAllWith(
        typeof(Module2UOWDecorator<>),
        instance => instance.ReturnedType.Assembly == typeof(Class2).Assembly));
```

Comment: I used your code, but this cause my `ICommandHandler` doesn't decorate with any decorator. How can I find, what is `instance` in run-time?

Comment: Hi @Masoud, I've updated the code - can you try again?